# when i import arcpy in python idle i get an error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-idle

when i type import arcpy i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from arcpy import da
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _base import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 578, in <module>
    env = GPEnvironments(gp)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 575, in GPEnvironments
    return GPEnvironment(geoprocessor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 531, in __init__
    self._refresh()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 533, in _refresh
    envset = (set(env for env in self._gp.listEnvironments()))
RuntimeError: NotInitialized
```

what should i do ?
i need to use arcpy in eclipse also and i can't!

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when there are not enough licenses to go around, or if your organization has disabled automated library downloading as part of their software suite.

Check what version of Python you're using in Eclipse, I know friends who've had to download condas in order to import arcpy without fail.